# Android - Border around ListFragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, border

I have an `Activity` that includes a `ListFragment` in the activity's xml file...

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/shoppingListNamesFragment"
    android:name="com.example.ShoppingListNamesFragment"
    android:layout_below="@id/shoppingListsTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I would like to put a border around this fragment. I have tried adding this to the above XML...

```
android:background="@drawable/white_dashed_border"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:layout_margin="14dp"
```

...but it doesn't create the border (whereas it does create a border if I add those 3 lines to the xml, for example, to a LinearLayout).

How do I add a border to the ListFragment (ideally by using xml)?

PS - There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266908/cant-add-border-on-map-fragment-android) which suggests adding a parent layout, but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You'd need to put the border on the root element of the fragments layout AFAIK

Comment: Do you have access to change the code of the ShoppingListNamesFragment fragment, or it is in a library that you have no control over? If you can change the code, you can have a custom theme you can apply just to that fragment that adds the border (shape drawable) as a background. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Add the border to the root element of your ListFragment's layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_dashed_border"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:layout_margin="14dp">
```

Comment: Cheers, but there are other elements in the LinearLayout that I don't want the border to go around.

Comment: How are you planning to add a border around the whole fragment without the border encompassing child elements of said fragment..?

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457135/how-to-add-border-around-linear-layout-except-at-the-bottom/30802089#30802089) may help you very easily, as well for this specific case (fragment) as for any widget.
It enables you to wrap any widget you want inside a pre-made and configurable bordered Framelayout.